# Change Source IP in socket sendto()

Tags: c, sockets, sendto

My function currently works correctly, however It's sending from my servers main IP address instead of another one.

Here is the snippet of code:

```
void *sendpacket(void *par1)
{
        running_threads++;
        int thread_id = (int)par1;
        unsigned long start_ip = htonl(ntohl(start)+(per_thread*thread_id));
        unsigned long end = htonl(ntohl(start)+(per_thread*(thread_id+1)));
        unsigned long w;
        int y;
        unsigned char buf[65536];
        strcpy(buf, "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:239.255.255.250:1900\r\nST:ssdp:all\r\nMan:\"ssdp:discover\"\r\nMX:3\r\n\r\n");
        int sizeofpayload = 90;
        int sock;
        if((sock=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))<0) {
                perror("cant open socket");
                exit(-1);
        }
        for(w=ntohl(start_ip);w<htonl(end);w++)
        {
                struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
                bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
                servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
                servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(w);
                servaddr.sin_port=htons(1900);
                sendto(sock,(char *)buf,sizeofpayload,0, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
                bytes_sent+=sizeofpayload;
                scanned++;
                hosts_done++;
                usleep(sleep_between*1000);
        }
        close(sock);
        running_threads--;
        return;
}
```

This sends a packet to the variable w, on port 1900 from my default server IP lets call it 192.168.0.1 however I want it to send the packet from 192.168.1.1 so forging the UDP packet to spoof to another address.

```
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(w);
```

Handles the destination address but I'm struggling to edit the source IP address.

Comment: I think you need raw sockets for that.

Comment: NOTE: `bytes_sent+=sizeofpayload;` wrong; you should sento()'s return value for that.

Comment: You need proper error handling. For example, if `sendto()` returns -1 you haven't sent any bytes at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If 192.168.1.1 is a local IP of the sending PC, you can `bind()` the socket to 192.168.1.1 before than calling `sendto()`.  Otherwise, you have to use a `SOCK_RAW` socket (which is restricted to admin users only) and create the IP and UDP headers manually.